# Does O_DIRECT bypass filesystem journaling?

Tags: linux, file, io, dma

The man page for open(2) only suggests that O_DIRECT bypasses the page cache, but many descriptions around the net describe it as causing the user buffer to be DMA'd straight to the drive. If this is the case I imagine it would also bypass journaling done by the filesystem (e.g. xfs, ext4, etc.). Is this the case?

I can't find anyone claiming one way or the other. It seems to me this would be consistent with O_DIRECT being used by databases -- the common example use for O_DIRECT is when an application like a database is doing its own caching in userspace, and similarly I can imagine databases doing their own transaction logs.

Answer (score 3):

> Does `O_DIRECT` bypass filesystem journaling?

Usually it does. However, file data usually doesn't go into a filesystem's journal anyway. More details below (but note this answer doesn't try to account for CoW filesystems):

Most Linux journaling filesystems (Ext4 when journal is set to writeback or ordered (the default), XFS, JFS etc) are not journalling the data within files - they are journaling the consistency of the filesystem's data structures (metadata).

**Filesystem journals only metadata (typical case):** Well data within the files doesn't go into the journal anyway so using `O_DIRECT` doesn't change this and the data continues to not to go into the journal. However, `O_DIRECT` operations can still trigger metadata updates just like normal but the initiating operation can return before the metadata has been updated. See the [Ext4 wiki Clarifying Direct IO's Semantics page](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Clarifying_Direct_IO%27s_Semantics) for details.

**Ext4 in journal=data mode**: This is trickier - there's a warning that the desired outcome with `O_DIRECT` in `journal=data` mode might not be what is expected . From the ["data=journal" section of ext4.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt):

> Enabling this mode [journal=data] will disable delayed allocation and `O_DIRECT` support.

In this scenario `O_DIRECT` is looked at as only a hint and the filesystem silently falls back to stuffing the data into the page cache (making it no longer direct!). So in this case yes the data will end up going into the journal and the journal won't be bypassed. See the "[Re: [PATCH 1/1 linux-next] ext4: add compatibility flag check](https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org/msg1279956.html)" thread for where Ted Ts'o articulates this. There are patches floating around ("[ext4: refuse O_DIRECT opens for mode where DIO doesn't work](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/614116/)") to make the filesystem return an error at open instead but from what I can see these were rejected from the mainline kernel.